# can I scan for beacons without specifying "region" is swift?

Tags: ios, swift, region, beacon

I have this code to scan beacons

```
    var closetBeacon: NSUUID?
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    let region = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: NSUUID(UUIDString: "B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D")!, identifier: "my_beacons")

func authorizeBeaconScan() -> Void{
        locationManager.delegate = self
        if (CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() != CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedWhenInUse) {
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        }
        locationManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region)
    }
```

I understand `region` is supposed to filter only beacons I care about.

1) If I have few beacons I care about, how do I pass them all to `CLBeaconRegion(..)`?

2) can I scan for beacon without specifying `region`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to have UUID of beacons to scan.
Without UUID you can't scan beacons.

**1)** You can scan all beacons of same UUID for region by only specifying UUID.

**2)** You can scan specific beacons of one group having common major value by specifying UUID and major value.

**3)** You can also scan for specific beacon by using UUID, major and minor value of that beacon.

You have to have at-least one UUID of beacon to create region and start scanning it.

Comment: how can i know all of my beacons have same UUID?

Comment: You can get the beacon UUID from your beacon provider.

Comment: how many beacons are related to the same UUID? is to all the beacons of a specific provider?

Comment: how can i pass multiple UUID to a region object?

Comment: you need to create multiple regions for different UUIDs